# Visual Effects View with blur turns dark gray

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

Currently we have a Visual Effects View that was added in storyboard like so:
[image: Storyboard]

The view is presented modally but for some strange reason I can see the image underneath blurred during the transition but when the transition is complete the blur turns a dark gray:[image: gray blur]

No code has been written yet, I'm trying to do this all in storyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the presentation style of your second view controller.

1. Select your second view controller
2. From the `Attributes Inspector` set `Presentation` to `Over Current Context`

   [image]

**Note:** Make sure your second view controller is presented modally.